# How to put two charts on the same page with different modules?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've put two charts on one page. The first chart (scatter) was created using a Highcharts and the second chart (line) was created using a Highstock. As the Highcharts is included in the Highstock so I use this:

```
<script src="resources/chart/Highstock/js/highstock.js"></script>   
<script src="resources/chart/Highstock/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

The part of my page looks like this:

```
<script src="resources/chart/Highstock/js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="resources/chart/Highstock/js/modules/boost.js"></script>   
<script src="resources/chart/Highstock/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> create the chart using the highcharts and put it in a containerForHighchart </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> create the chart using the highstock and put it in a containerForHighstock </script>

<div id="containerForHighchart" style="height: 700px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
<div id="containerForHighstock" style="height: 700px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Now: I'd like to achieve something like this:

- The first chart (highcharts) should use the `boost.js` module.
- The second chart (highstock) shouldn't use the `boost.js` module.

Why? Due to performance and some bug. Both charts have to display a lot of data.

When I use `boost.js` and put only one chart on the page:

- the chart of highstock is loading very slowly, most of the time the browser inform me that the page isn't responding and at the end I can only see a navigator without the chart;
- the chart of highchart is loading fast.

When I don't use `boost.js` and put only one chart on the page:

- the chart of highstock is loading fast;
- the chart of highchart is loading too long and is very slow.

Is there any way to only one of the two charts use the `boost.js` module on the same page?

Comment: The boost.js file overwrites some methods form Highcharts, so you cannot choose if chart should be build-in by boost or not. Anyway this is a good idea, so I advice you to post your suggestion in our uservoice here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll do it. BTW: Is there any way to the scatter chart from Highstock without the `boost.js` module run as fast as the scatter chart from Highcharts with the `boost.js` module? The scatter chart from Highstock with the `boost.js` module run very slow (I read the advices about setting options [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/modules/boost.src.js) but the chart still works bad. It run very slow as well if I don't use the `boost.js` module (in my case the `dataGrouping` option has to be false) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution you could try is to put the charts in separate web pages (by themselves) and use `<iframe>` tags to place them both in a single HTML document. That way, you could control which chart gets which libraries, and they shouldn't conflict with one another.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed I use a JSF and a CDI bean as a controller (view scope) which controls my page. This bean is very important because there're my data which I've to display. The data is sent to bean from some form. I didn't tell about it because I didn't think that it would be necessary. The `<iframe>` tag creates own/new bean instead of using the current bean, so the data (which I've to display) are lost. This's why I cannot use the `<iframe>` tag as simple as you said.

Comment: Of course your solution is good as the answer to my question above, so I'll accept it but if you've another solutions, feel free to tell me about it ;)